Get a SharePoint list item using custom field inside my PnP Core SDK console application
I have a PnP Core Sdk console application, and I have a SharePoint list titled as "System Setting and Configuration", and it has a field named "SettingReferecne" & "SettingValue", now i am trying to get the setting value using the setting reference, as follow:-
var settingList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("System Setting and Configuration");

var WOHWItem = settingList.Items.AsRequested().FirstOrDefault(p => p["SettingReference"].ToString() == "14");

var WOHWs = WOHWItem["SettingValue"].ToString().Split(';');

but the var WOHWItem will always be null.. any advice?
